# Regex... less as possible

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have this text of people names and their historical birthdays:

> Прп. Моисея Мурина (ок. 400). Обре́тение мощей прп. Иова Почаевского (1659). Собор преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских, в Дальних пещерах (прп. Феодосия) почивающих. Прп. Саввы Крыпецкого, Псковского (1495). Прав. Анны пророчицы, дщери Фануилевой, встретившей Господа Иисуса Христа в храме Иерусалимском (I). Мц. Шушаники, кн. Ранской (V) (Груз.). Сщмч. Алексия Будрина (1918); прмчч. Казанских: Сергия Зайцева, Лаврентия Никитина, Серафима Кузьмина, Феодосия Александрова, Леонтия Карягина, Стефана, Георгия Тимофеева, Илариона Правдина, Иоанна Сретенского и Сергия Галина (1918). Прп. Исаакия Оптинского (1894). Сщмч. Александра Медведева диакона (1918); сщмч. Николая Георгиевского пресвитера (1931); сщмч. Василия Сокольского пресвитера (1937). Грузинской иконы Божией Матери (1650).

The task is to regex only those people with a birthday older then 1900.
in this example the regex should mark:

> Сщмч. Алексия Будрина (1918); прмчч. Казанских: Сергия Зайцева, Лаврентия Никитина, Серафима Кузьмина, Феодосия Александрова, Леонтия Карягина, Стефана, Георгия Тимофеева, Илариона Правдина, Иоанна Сретенского и Сергия Галина (1918). Сщмч. Александра Медведева диакона (1918); сщмч. Николая Георгиевского пресвитера (1931); сщмч. Василия Сокольского пресвитера (1937).

I tried this regular expression:

```
(?<=\)\.)(.)+?\((19|20)\d{2}\)\.
```

with a positiv lookbehind (?<=) for finding ').' but somehow it goes above the first match and tries to get as much as possible..
like:

> Обре́тение мощей прп. Иова Почаевского (1659). Собор преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских, в Дальних пещерах (прп. Феодосия) почивающих. Прп. Саввы Крыпецкого, Псковского (1495). Прав. Анны пророчицы, дщери Фануилевой, встретившей Господа Иисуса Христа в храме Иерусалимском (I). Мц. Шушаники, кн. Ранской (V) (Груз.). Сщмч. Алексия Будрина (1918); прмчч. Казанских: Сергия Зайцева, Лаврентия Никитина, Серафима Кузьмина, Феодосия Александрова, Леонтия Карягина, Стефана, Георгия Тимофеева, Илариона Правдина, Иоанна Сретенского и Сергия Галина (1918). Прп. Исаакия Оптинского (1894). Сщмч. Александра Медведева диакона (1918); сщмч. Николая Георгиевского пресвитера (1931); сщмч. Василия Сокольского пресвитера (1937).

with parts like ...

> Обре́тение мощей прп. Иова Почаевского (1659). Собор преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских, в Дальних пещерах (прп. Феодосия) почивающих. Прп. Саввы Крыпецкого, Псковского (1495). Прав. Анны пророчицы, дщери Фануилевой, встретившей Господа Иисуса Христа в храме Иерусалимском (I). Мц. Шушаники, кн. Ранской (V) (Груз.).

or...

> Прп. Исаакия Оптинского (1894).

what would be a right expression to match it properly?

for instance: it should match

).**SOMETHING**(19\d\d).

Comment: The right solution is to extract all the data with a regular expression, then filter with some other code. What's the environment you're working in?

Comment: I would extract all digits, and then depending on the language, using basic logic to check < 1900.

Comment: For non-Russian speakers, where exactly do the names start and end? Is "Собор преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских, в Дальних пещерах (прп. Феодосия) почивающих. Прп. Саввы Крыпецкого, Псковского" all one person?

Comment: yes it is, it counts the same way like a person.

Comment: "Собор преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских, в Дальних пещерах (прп. Феодосия) почивающих. Прп. Саввы Крыпецкого, Псковского" counts the same way like a person. But on't forget the "(1495)." is needed, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(?<=\)[.;])\s*([^()]+\((?:19|20)\d\d\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lY6jT8/1)

Non-greedy quantifiers only affect where the match ends, not where it starts.  You need to find something you can exclude to prevent it starting too early.  In this case, excluding parentheses (`[^()]+`) seems to work, but I can't guarantee it always will.  Names like:

```
Bill S. Preston (Esq.) (1970)
```

...will make the task much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunalety, not a russian speeker, but does this one get your started?

```
[\p{L},\h]+
\(1[0-8]\d{2}\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1eV1/2). To expand the name part, include other characters to the class (e.g. `.`)

---

<sup>As mentioned by others, it's probably easier to grab all dates and anaylze them programmatically afterwards.</sup>